# Convert ArrayList<String> to byte[]

Tags: java, string, encryption, arraylist, byte

I want to be able to convert an `ArrayList<String>` that stores the contents of a file read from a BufferedReader, then convert the contents into a byte[] to allow it to be encrypted using Java's Cipher class.

I have tried using `.getBytes()` but it's not working since I think I need to convert the ArrayList first, and I'm having trouble on figuring out how to do that.

Code:

```
// File variable
private static String file;

// From main()
file = args[2];

private static void sendData(SecretKey desedeKey, DataOutputStream dos) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> fileString = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        String userFile = file + ".txt";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userFile));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            fileString.add(line.getBytes()); //error here
        }

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desedeKey);
        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(fileString.getBytes("UTF-8")); //error here
        dos.writeInt(output.length);
        dos.write(output);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + Arrays.toString(output));
    }
```

Many thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either concatenate strings, or create a `StringBuffer`.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
String userFile = file + ".txt";

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userFile));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   buffer.append(line); //error here
}

byte[] bytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();
```

Answer (score 6):

Why would you want to read it as string and the convert it to byte array? Since Java 7 you can do:

```
byte[] input= Files.readAllBytes(new File(userFile.toPath());
```

then pass that content to the Cipher.

```
byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(input);
```

Also you might consider using streams (InputStream and CipherOutputStream) instead of loading the whole file into the memory in case you need handle big files.

Answer (score 0):

So, the full `ArrayList` is in fact a single `String`?

One straightforward approach would be to merge all the `Strings` in it into a single one and then call the `.getBytes()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use ArrayList. Just use a StringBuffer and keep the complete contents of the file into a single string.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to take advantage of Java's serialization functionality and use an ObjectOutputStream wrapped around a ByteOutputStream:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bout)) {
  out.writeObject(list);
  out.flush();

  byte[] data = bout.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Do something with the exception
}
```

The downside to this approach is that the contents of the byte array will be tied to the list implementation's serialized form, so reading it back into a List may give weird results in later Java versions.